# Can I wrap master page div tags around existing div tags in the pages of my asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm incorporating all of the schema.org microdata into my website. My website has 47 pages, however, with 5 master pages.

Much of the code in my .resx resource files (10 different languages) already has div tags in it.  But can I just, for instance, take the lazy way out and put an opening div tag at the top of a master page, and a closing div tag at the bottom of the master page?

For instance, this is the normal syntax for microdata:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Jason Weber</span> has a background in economics, and brings his 
experience to <span itemprop="company">USS Vision</span>.
</div>
```

But I already have many div tags in my pages.  So can I just go to a master page, and at the top of the master page, put:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/company"> (top of master page)
--------- below is the individual page ---------
This is where each page will differ.  There is much text in here, as well as pictures, 
and other things.  Much of this already has div tags in it.  So if I don't want to 
print something, I already <div class="noprint"><span class="tablestyle3">have div 
classes in there</span></div>.
--------- above is the individual page ---------
</div> (bottom of master page)
```

This is me thinking of a lazy, easy way out, but isn't that what asp.net and master pages are for?  So if you can follow my thinking, is this proper?  **Can I surround div tags with master page div tags**?  Or do I really need to delve into all 47 pages and put individual div tags in each page?  Even if it came to that, I'd still do it; I'm sold on the schema.org microdata.  Thank you for any guidance anybody can offer!

Comment: Remember, when it comes to `HTML`, your content will eventually be parsed and interpreted by a browser. `HTML`, unless it's being interpreted on the server, is a display layer, so "do what you will" only if the browser understands it.

Comment: I'm not an ASP.NET developer, so apologies in advance if this isn't useful, but look at [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). You can also do this with Javascript, on the client.

Comment: Thank you Jared for responding ... I'll check out that Twig link; although it's geared toward php, maybe I'll gain something from it.  Thanks!

Comment: I wish I knew what to suggest for ASP.NET. I've used Smarty and will be using Twig on a future project; note, you can do templates on the client, especially with Knockout.js, Backbone.js, Underscore.js, etc. If it's a single-page app. There's also Mustache.js, Handlebars.js, etc. Lots of richness here. Twig is cool, but on the client, there's a whole new world, unless you want it pre-rendered (on the server), where you probably need an ASP.NET template system. But the logic case is compelling for Twig, if it's available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But can I just, for instance, take the lazy way out and put an opening div tag at the top of a master page, and a closing div tag at the bottom of the master page?

You can absolutely do this. The only thing to really be concerned with is that once the page is rendered is the markup valid (or at least valid enough to suit you).

I.e. As long as your rendered HTML is not broken, than how you organize your Master Pages is not such a big deal.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, for taking the time to read and respond.  I guess that was really my question; is the markup going to be rendered valid by all browsers?  But I think I understand you, that you CAN wrap div tags around other div tags, and it will be rendered valid if all the other syntax is proper.  Thank you again, Kevin, for the information!

Comment: @JasonWeber - Take a look at http://validator.w3.org/, where you can provide a public URL or copy/paste to check the markup's validity.

Comment: Thanks Jared; I'm doing that right now!  I've used that website before, but I had forgotten about it, so now I'll check it to see if these div tags (around existing div tags) are being accepted.

Comment: Awesome!  I'm testing it in Google's structured data webmaster tools thing, and everything is working out perfectly!  Thanks again Kevin, Jared!